# Jackson Streaming API vs Jackson mappers

Tags: json, spring, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have read how to use Jackson Streaming API as well as Jackson mappers for object-Json conversion and vice-versa but for my spring project which one should i use.

It was written Streaming API is most powerful but i find mappers really easy to use and easily understandable.

My question is how Streaming API is powerful than mappers and which one is better to use in terms of usage in a big spring project?

Comment: When is it a good idea to load the whole contents of a file in memory, and when is it a better idea to read the file line by line and process each line one by one? I'd say that it mostly depend on the size of the file, the number of files to process concurrently, the available memory, and the relative difficulty of the two possible solutions. wouldn't you? Same for JSON.

Comment: yes it will depend on the size of the data, but in both the cases it has to be written to disk so where is the difference. Also, how is streaming api powerful than the mappers.

Comment: I don't really understand why the JSON would have to be stored on the disk, but you don't seem to have understood my previous comment. If you have 500 MB of memory, loading a JSON which is 600MB large in memory and then writing those 600 MB to disk won't work. Loading it 1MB per 1 MB, and writing each MB to disk before loading the next one  will work fine.

Comment: yes, this is true I understand that but how is this related to mappers and streaming api?

Comment: Well, using a mapper means that you load the whole JSON document in memory as a mapped Java object, whereas the streaming API, as its name indicates, makes you treat the JSON document as a stream of JSON tokens, that you consume one by one. The API is harder to use, much more low-level, but doesn't force you to load everything in memoty and to map the whole JSON to a Java object.

Comment: okay, now i get it. thanks @JBNizet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jackson Mappers:**

when using Jackson Mappers, we load the entire JSON document into the memory as a Java object. This may be a problem if one has very large set of data. for example if mappers are used in a very big project, your memory limit is only 512MB but the size of JSON is 600MB, in this case the application will crash. In such situations use of Streaming API is preferred.

**Jackson Streaming API :**

when using jackson Streaming API, we can load json data token by token i.e. as the name suggests streaming api treats the json document as stream of json tokens that can be consumed one by one with no memory problems. But if memory requirement is not much Mappers are preferred because they are fast and efficient.

**The second part of the question,**

How is Streaming API more powerful than mappers?

Well, since json document is treated as stream of tokens we can manipulate  tokens as per our requirements and use them. Mappers only provide fetch and store functionality. The Streaming API is much low-level with more power given to the developer.

The API being low-level is more hard to use and sometimes confusing whereas the mapper functionality is easy to use.